# Youtube Data API Search Returning Repeating Items

Tags: search, pagination, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

(Duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72082123/youtube-data-api-search-issue-next-page-results-contain-previous-pages-videos) since I don't have enough rep to add a comment).

Essentially when using Search and using the page token to get more results, the results in the following pages tend to have results from the previous pages. The more pages you go through, the more and more repeating videos appear.

You can test this directly via [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list?apix=true&apix_params=%7B%22part%22%3A%5B%22snippet%22%5D%2C%22maxResults%22%3A25%2C%22q%22%3A%22hololive%22%7D) which allows you to perform calls from there. Do a search query for anything, keep track of the video IDs in the results, wait a few seconds, and then do another query with the next page token, and repeat. It sometimes takes around 5 or so pages before a duplicate shows up. The same issue happens if you search for related videos instead of a query.

Is this intended behavior? I cannot seem to locate anything in the documentation mentioning this. I may be wrong, but I feel like this issue only started happening this month because I did not notice this behavior in an application I was working on around a month ago.

Comment: YouTube Data API v3 has *some bugs*. If you don't treat duplicate items as many times as they are present, is there a problem otherwise (like an item not showing up while it should) ?

Comment: If you are still unable to comment, don't hesitate to answer my question by editing your question if you are able to.

Comment: @BenjaminLoison Sorry, I'm not quite sure what you're asking/suggesting by treating duplicate items. Other than duplicates though, everything works fine. The problem I noticed is that after a while there are more and more duplicates that show up per page; sometimes only duplicates if you set it to only give back like 5 items per page.

Comment: For your information the [Search: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) endpoint [is limited to 500 results](https://github.com/Benjamin-Loison/YouTube-operational-API/issues/4) both on the YouTube Data API v3 side and the YouTube UI side: https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=YOUR_SEARCH_QUERY

Comment: I am having this same problem. When I run the same query again, the appearance of duplicates is different, but the total number of videos returned is the same. This suggests that the duplicates are taking the place of other videos that should be in the list.